# How to create floating ContentDialogue in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to create a messagebox or ContentDialogue which can be easily dragged with mouse like this: 
[image]

How can I do this ?

Comment: I don't belief this to be possible in UWP.

Comment: Then how did Microsoft do this in Groove Music app?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the `ContentDialog` design is built this way and cannot be separated into a "secondary view".

The confirmation dialog you mention in Groove Music is actually a `MessageDialog`, which appears as a modal window, but this one is not very customizable (you can set custom buttons and text only).

If you really wanted to build such dialog, you would have to do this yourself by creating a [new app view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views), that will act as if it is a dialog. However, this app view will not be a modal one, so you would also have to disable the first app view somehow (like overlying a semi-transparent border above the content).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Popup control and manipulation event handlers on the contents.  I wrote an example [here](https://github.com/mscherotter/UWPChildWindow) that demonstrates the method.

The code also shows how to make an independent window with the same content.